# Passing into a directive without adding it to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive where a list(array) of items is passed in through the scope of the controller into the scope of the directive whereby the template of the directive then has access to the items.

I would like to have it so that the list of items is passed to the directive (where it is then used within the link function) and then not directly accessible through the directive's template.

i.e. if we had the following directive:

```
directive('itemList', function(){
return {
    scope: {
        items: '='
    }
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        var item-list = scope.items;
        // ... want to manipulate first ...
    }
}
})
```

the variable scope.items is now available to any template that the directive uses. Whereas I don't want that to be the case and would like to pass in something to the directive without making it known to the scope. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the directive scope pretty much by definition is the scope used by the directive's template, I don't see any obvious way of doing this in a strict information hiding way. But, why not just use a different name for the passed scope variable and what the template binds to? For example, if you said `scope: { myPrivatePassedItems: '=items' }`, you can now work with `scope.myPrivatePassedItems` as much as needed before setting it as `scope.items`. With this approach, the HTML in both the usage of the directive and the directive's template just sees "items", but internally your directive has its own "private" variable.

I should add that the above is the simple change needed for the one-way data flow from the consumer to the directive template. If you also need to update the original items array, you will also want to add a `scope.$watch` on the `scope.items` array after you have done your initial setup. You would then need to carry those changes (possibly with modifications) back to `scope.myPrivatePassedItems` in order to update the consumer's array.

Comment: This is the approach I went for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$parse` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) to retrieve the value without using `scope: {}`, but you will lose the 2 way data binding that you inherently get from using `scope: { items: '=' }`. As mentioned by Dana Cartwright, if you need 2 way binding, you have to set this up manually with watches.

```
directive('itemList', function($parse){
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            var itemList = $parse(attrs['items'])(scope);

            // do stuff with itemList
            // ...
            // then expose it
            scope.itemList = itemList;
        }
    };
});
```